# Updating SQL database column updates all rows with the same data

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I am currently using the following PHP to select plain-text passwords from my database, use bcrypt to hash them, and then update them in the table:

PHP:

```
    $select = "SELECT Password
FROM Login";
$result = $conn->query($select);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Password: " . $row["Password"]. "<br>";
        $hashed_password = password_hash($row["Password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = "UPDATE login SET Password='$hashed_password' ";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        echo " Succesfully Updated. <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

However, it updates with the same hash (password) for each value:

--- LOGIN ---
Login ID: 1 Password-Hash: z39kjddddddddddd
Login ID: 2 Password-Hash: z39kjddddddddddd
Login ID: 3 Password-Hash: z39kjddddddddddd

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the script `$sql = "UPDATE login SET Password='$hashed_password' ";` which lacks the `WHERE` clause, definitely, all the data in your table will only have 1 kind of hashed password

I suggest

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET Password='$hashed_password' WHERE id =".$row["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you get all the passwords but you don't get the primary key for each row. How then will you know which row to update? 
You must also get the primary key for the table and use that to update the row.

*Assuming that your table has a row named 'id' which is the primary key.*

```
$select = "SELECT id, Password FROM Login";
$result = $conn->query($select);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "Password: " . $row["Password"]. "<br>";
        $hashed_password = password_hash($row["Password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = "UPDATE `login` SET Password='$hashed_password' WHERE `id` = {$id}";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo " Successfully Updated. <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

You might want to consider finding a way to know if the password is already updated and only update those rows that were not updated.

Answer (score 0):

in order to update we need to use a where clause. in your code there is no where clause.

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET Password='$hashed_password' ";
```

it should be like

```
 sql = "UPDATE login SET Password='$hashed_password' WHERE id =".$row["id"];
```